# Unable to resolve Grails custom validator issue

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-2.3, grails-validation

I am using spring security core plugin in my grails project and the Person domain looks something like this.

```
class User {

transient springSecurityService

//Mandatory Fields
String employeeId
String firstName
String lastName
String password
String emailId

//Other Fields
String department
String extn

String mobileNumber
String address
String city
String zipCode
String country

User manager

static hasMany = [previousPasswords: String]

boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static transients = ['springSecurityService']

static constraints = {
    employeeId blank: false, unique: true
    firstName blank: false
    lastName blank: false
    password blank: false, password: true, validator: {val, obj ->
        if(obj.previousPasswords) {
            println "-----------------------1-------------------------"
            println "obj.previousPasswords: " + obj.previousPasswords
            println "val: " + val
            if (obj.isDirty('password')) {
                println "-----------------------2-------------------------"
                if(obj.previousPasswords.contains(val)) {
                    obj.errors.rejectValue(
                        'password',
                        'user.password.duplicated',
                        'Repeat passwords are not allowed')
                    return false
                }
                println "-----------------------3-------------------------"
                obj.addToPreviousPasswords(val)
                return true
            }
        } else {
            println "-----------------------4-------------------------"
            obj.addToPreviousPasswords(val)
            return true
        }
    }
    emailId blank: false, email: true

    department nullable: true
    extn nullable: true

    mobileNumber nullable: true
    address nullable: true
    city nullable: true
    zipCode nullable: true
    country nullable: true

    manager nullable: true
}

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
}

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}

def beforeInsert() {
    println "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        println "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
        encodePassword()
    }
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}
}
```

I have to ensure that passwords are not repeated for which I have written a custom validator for 'password' field

My Integration test looks like this

```
void "Test if previous passwords can be re-used"() {
    given:
    def user = new User(employeeId: "empId1", firstName: "f_name", lastName: "l_name", password: "password", emailId: "test@hptest.com", mobileNumber: "(111) 111-1111", address: "350 Fifth Avenue, 34th floor", city: "New York", zipCode: "10007")
    println "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  1  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
    user.springSecurityService = springSecurityService
    println "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  2  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
    user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    when: 'password is repeated'
    user.password = "password"
    println "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  3  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
    user.save(flush: true)

    then: 'validation fails'
    !user.validate()
    user.errors.getFieldError("password").codes.contains("validator.invalid")

    when: 'password is not repeated'
    user.password = "password@123"

    then: 'validation succeeds'
    println "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  4  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
    user.validate()
    println "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  5  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
    user.save(flush: true)
}
```

and the output I am getting is like this

```
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  1  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  2  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
-----------------------4-------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
-----------------------1-------------------------
obj.previousPasswords: [password]
val: $2a$10$mxFM9S7mEoOdyRo6xJL9/uzVafUgc0.8r1rd4nzBYM45s2cE8TTDi
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&  3  &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
-----------------------1-------------------------
obj.previousPasswords: [password]
val: password
-----------------------2-------------------------
-----------------------1-------------------------
obj.previousPasswords: [password]
val: password
```

If you carefully study the code and the output you would find that the validator function is called twice for every save operation.

Can anyone tell me what is the reason for this. Could this be due to the addTo method that I am using within validator?

Comment: what about unique constarint?

Comment: unique constraint should not be a problem. It has been defined for employeeId. The problem occurs in the custom validator for password.

Comment: u can apply the same constraint for this too.Already it exists, why custom validation?

Comment: unique constraint would mean that passwords cannot be same for different users. My requirement is different. I want to ensure that users donot use passwords that they have used previously.

Comment: oh ok.ok.i understand now.this is like change password right?

Comment: yes. the same functionality that google uses while changing passwords.

Comment: ok.give me 5mins.i will tell

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52204/discussion-between-visme-and-rammohan)

Answer (score 1):

Shall i tell another way.Remove custom validation.

When user change password, check whether this password already exists in previousPasswords.if exists, give message like already used.if not, save the user with new password and add it to previousPasswords.

```
 def changePassword(){
       def userIns = User.get(params.userId)
       def previousPasswords = userIns.previousPasswords()
       def exists = previousPasswords.find{it == params.newPassword}
       if(exists){
           msg = "Already Used. Give new"
           render changepassword screen
           return false
       }
       else{
           userIns.password = params.newPw
           userIns.addToPreviousPasswords(params.newPw)
           userIns.save(flush:true)
           msg = "successfully changed"
       }
    }
```

Comment: hmmm. The work around seems to be worth a try. Will try and let you know.

Comment: what grails version are you using?

Comment: I am yet to do it. Will probably finish it by today.

Comment: delete custom validation and clear the classes under target folder,if u face any problem.what grils version are you using?

Comment: I changed the code as you had suggested and it worked. Thanks. I am using grails 2.3.7.